# Does New-AzureReservedIP on in-use IP address cause downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

A very quick question to which I couldn't find a definitive answer elsewhere. If I use New-AzureReservedIP in conjunction with the -ServiceName parameter to reserve the current active public IP address of a running cloud service then does this carry any risk of causing downtime to the cloud service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't actually reserve the current in-use IP. This command will create a new reserved IP, and then move the service onto it. It may cause an interruption if things are pointing to the old (not reserved) IP.

Details (which you may have already seen) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ddc52dc-e455-4fb0-b072-34104cfd45c4/how-to-reserve-virtual-pulic-ip-for-already-created-vm-in-azure?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Thanks, I obviously misunderstood what the new changes were meant to do.

Comment: so because im using a cname ... then... no downtime right? wont the machine be "restarted or something"?